# Find iOS UIImageview and UITextview by tag

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextview

I use this code to find the right `UIImageView` by tag in my `iOS` app and it works.

```
selectedView = ((UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:x]);
```

Where x is a NSInteger.

Now, i have a `UITextview` with the same tag of the `UIImageView`.

Is there a method that returns only the `UIImageView` or only the `Textview` with this tag and not all the `Views`?

like:

```
selectedImageView = ((UIImageView*)[... viewWithTag:x]);

selectedTextView = ((UITextView*)[... viewWithTag:x]);
```

Comment: Why are you using the same tag for both subviews?

Comment: I have a loop in which i create images and textview dynamically. Every image has a univocal id returned by the database (it's a int), so i use this value as tag to know in which row i am

Comment: This is why using tags in this case is brittle. It's more robust to use actual object references for comparison instead.

Comment: now it works fine, i know that's not the best solution but i thought it was the easiest. i'm new in iOS programming, i don't understand what method you mean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that:

```
- (id) viewWithTag:(NSUInteger) tag andClass:(Class) className
{
    for(UIView* subview in [self.view subviews])
    {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:className] && subview.tag == tag)
        {
            return subview;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: This won't really work. The call to `viewWithTag:` will return the 1st subview it finds with the given tag. If it's not the desired view, there is no way to get the desired one.

Comment: so, isn't there a method to find all the views with this tag, and not only the first?

Comment: Check my updated answer. I'm not searching recursively here, but mabye it's enough for you.

Comment: If i use it for class UIImageView it works (isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]) but it doesn't work for class UITextView (isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]), it's not my problem because i haven't to use it for UITextView class (the first view with that tag is the textview so i don't need the loop), but i can't understand why it happens.

Comment: Hm maybe you have some custom class there, try NSLog the class type to see

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to use different tags for each of the views.

Comment: True but only for viewWithTag. It's not required to have different tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a simple category to do what you want. In your case, something like the following may work.

```
@interface UIView (MultitagSupport)
- (NSArray *)viewsWithTag:(NSInteger)tag andClass:(Class)class;
@end
```

-

```
@implementation UIView (MultitagSupport)

- (NSArray *)viewsWithTag:(NSInteger)tag andClass:(Class)class
{
    NSMutableArray* matches = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (UIView* subview in self.subviews)
    {
        if (subview.tag == tag && [subview isKindOfClass:class])
        {
            [matches addObject:subview];
        }
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:matches]; // return immutable copy for safety
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try filtering the subviews with a predicate:

```
    NSArray *foundImageViews = [self.view.subviews filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
      [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag = %d && class = %@", 1, 
      [UIImageView class]]];
```

That would return all UIImageView subviews tagged '1'